# Are all Helmholtz decompositions related?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, differential-calculus, vector-spaces

Suppose $V\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be non-empty and at least twice differentiable (Smooth) and let $S$ be the surface that encloses $V$ (for example a sphere). Let $\textbf{F}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth vector field for all space. Let $\textbf{n}$ denote the normal to the surface $S$. It is well known using Helmhotz decompostion that we can decompose $\textbf{F}$ into two vector fields in $V$; $$\textbf{F} = \nabla \sigma + \nabla \times \Gamma$$ where $\nabla \sigma$ is called the irrotatioal part and $\nabla \times \Gamma$ the selonodial part of $\textbf{F}$. This decomposositon is known not to be unique. I want to know if the class of all solutions are related. For example take $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, $\Gamma_1$, and $\Gamma_2$ so that $$\textbf{F} = \nabla \sigma_1 + \nabla \times \Gamma_1 = \nabla \sigma_2 + \nabla \times \Gamma_2$$ and then $$ \nabla (\sigma_1- \sigma_2) + \nabla \times (\Gamma_1- \Gamma_2)  = \textbf{0}.$$ This should happen only if both these vector fields vanish. Or $$ \nabla \times (\Gamma_1- \Gamma_2) = \textbf{0}$$ $$ \nabla (\sigma_1- \sigma_2) = \textbf{0}.$$ Is there anything we can say about the solutions (i,e are they linear independent or multiples of one another).

Comment: your final two equations are not correct, the gradient of the difference $\sigma_1-\sigma_2$ need not vanish, its _Laplacian_ should vanish (see the answer box).

Comment: A term to search for here is *de Rham cohomology*

Comment: hmmmmm ill look into it thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Q:** *How are two Helmholtz decompositions related?*

**A:** The scalar fields differ by a *harmonic function*.

Starting from a first decomposition $\sigma_1,\Gamma_1$, you can construct a second one by adding to $\sigma_1$ a harmonic function $h$,
$$\sigma_2=\sigma_1+h,\;\;\text{with}\;\;\nabla^2 h=0.$$
Then the matching $\Gamma_2$ is determined by the equation
$$\nabla\times(\Gamma_1-\Gamma_2)=\nabla h.$$

Comment: ahh I see thanks. So any harmonic function will produce another one. I'm guessing this must be the entire family of solutions.

Comment: indeed; of course, the boundary conditions may prevent you from finding a harmonic function, in which case the Helmholtz decomposition is unique

Comment: I think here we must have the gradient of harmonic functions are zero then?

Comment: no, the laplacian of the harmonic function is zero, not the gradient.

Comment: I see the $h$ cancels lol mybad

Comment: @carloBeenaker can we show all solution differ by a harmonic function. So if $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ are two selonidial parts does it neccasarrily follow that a harmonic function exist so that $\nabla\times \Gamma_1 = \nabla\times  \Gamma_2 + \nabla h$

Comment: yes, that is your third equation, with $h=\sigma_2-\sigma_1$; by taking the divergence of that equation you then find that $\nabla^2 h=0$.

Comment: this only shows us how to construct another solution provided we already have one. This doesn't tell us that they are related by $h$.

Comment: _theorem:_ the scalar fields of any two Helholtz decompositions differ by a harmonic function; this follows directly by taking the curl of your third equation.